# how to divide the events across different units in dhtmlx scheduler in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, dhtml

Hi i am using dhtmlx scheduler.

I have create the units tab. But i am not getting how to divide the events across different units. Here is my code.

```
 this.Scheduler = new DHXScheduler();

            Scheduler.InitialDate = DateTime.Now.Date;// the initial data of Scheduler   

            var unit = new UnitsView("Employee", "EmpID");//initializes the view

            var rooms = new List<object>(){
                new { key = "1", label = "Employee1"},
                new { key = "2", label = "Employee2"},
                new { key = "3", label = "Employee3"},
                new { key = "4", label = "Employee4"},
                new { key = "5", label = "Employee5"},
                new { key = "6", label = "Employee6"}
                };

            unit.Label = "Employee";
            unit.Property = "ID";
            unit.Size = 5;

            unit.AddOptions(rooms);

            Scheduler.Views.Add(unit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need this line

```
unit.Property = "ID";
```

i think events should be devided to units by 'EmpID' property, which is passed to the constructor